# Speed up multiplying two arrays for convolution

Tags: convolution

I've got an application and Ive done some speed profiling on my code and the limiting factor is the multiplication of two arrays. I've got one array X as follows (in my real code is it a 2000 elements long not 15) :

> a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o

and a second array Y (in my real code it is 300 elements long not 6) as follows :

> A B C D E F

I then multiply the arrays as follows to create a new array C:

```
value 1  A*a+B*b+C*c+D*d+E*e+F*f
value 2  A*b+B*c+C*d+D*e+E*f+F*g
value 3  A*c+B*d+C*e+D*f+E*g+F*h
value 4  A*d+B*e+C*f+D*g+E*h+F*i
value 5  A*e+B*f+C*g+D*h+E*i+F*j
value 6  A*f+B*g+C*h+D*i+E*j+F*k
value 7  A*g+B*h+C*i+D*j+E*k+F*l
value 8  A*h+B*i+C*j+D*k+E*l+F*m
value 9  A*i+B*j+C*k+D*l+E*m+F*n
value 10 A*j+B*k+C*l+D*m+E*n+F*o
```

I was wondering if there was a way to speed this code up. I currently just use the code:

```
for (int l=0; l<X.length; l++) {
    val=0;
    for (int i=0; i<X.length; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<J.length; j++)
            val+=X[i]*Y[j];
    C[l]=val;
}
```

I though I could maybe use Fourier transforms but it is slower than multiplying it out.

Comment: That inner loop doesn't look right for a convolution.  Don't you need something more like val+=X[i+l]*Y[j], with a different exit condition to prevent out-of-bounds accesses to X?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a BLAS implementation, which is the de facto standard scientific library for performing basic vector/matrix operations. There's probably a highly optimized version of BLAS available for your architecture of choice, using SIMD instructions (if there are any) and taking care of pipeline saturation to achieve maximum throughput. 
For example: OS X and iOS ships with a BLAS implementation in the Accelerate.framework.

(Please also note, that your code doesn't do convolution. *val* only depends on *i* and *j*, so each element of *C* will be the same: the sum of the products of each pair from *X* and *J*. )

Comment: Ok, thanks. Was hoping there would be a trick I could use to speed it up. Im using it on Android and have found renderscript the fastest so probably wouldnt use BLAS.